# Filter Gmail labels by parent for deletion after certain number of days

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I've given up on trying to manage my Gmail by Categories as they don't filter well in third-party email tools on my phone, so I've resorted to filtering all of my newsletters, blog posts, coupons, etc. into labels and sub-labels.

I have a GScript function to delete labels after a certain amount of days, but I can't figure out how to have the code include the parent/child label as well.

For example, I have a label called "-Newsletters" and a bunch of sub-labels for the type of newsletter (i.e., -Newsletters/Blogs, -Newsletters/Coupon, -Newsletter/News, etc.).  The code I have shown below works great when I'm searching for the exact label, but I'm trying to modify it so that it will run the code on all parent/child labels I may set up in the future.

Is there a way to do this with the GmailApp.search function?  or do I just need to repeat the code for each separate search string?

The code below deletes all emails with a label "-Newsletters" older than 3 days, but not 
"-Newsletters/Blogs" or "-Newsletters/News".  I'm not sure how I would setup a variable to capture the child label name or how to place that variable inside the GmailApp.search function.

Thanks in advance.

```
function cleanUpNewsletterLabel() {
  var delayDays = 3 // Enter # of days before messages are moved to trash
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays);
  var threads = GmailApp.search('label:-Newsletters -is:starred'); // filter all emails with -Newsletters label not starred
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
      {
        threads[i].moveToTrash();
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a [search operator](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) that you can use to get all child labels (only exact match seems to be supported).

What you can do instead, is retrieve all the child labels the following way:

- Retrieve all labels with [getUserLabels()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getUserLabels()).
- Filter this labels with the condition that their names start with the parent label name, since child label names have this format: `{parentLabelName}/{childLabelName}/...`. Here, you could use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith).
- For each filtered label, search the corresponding threads.

It could be something like this:

```js
const parentLabelName = "-Newsletters";
const labels = GmailApp.getUserLabels();
const filteredLabels = labels.filter(label => label.getName().startsWith(parentLabelName));
filteredLabels.forEach(filteredLabel => {
  const threads = GmailApp.search(`label:${filteredLabel.getName()} -is:starred`);
  // Delete threads (your code)
});
```